# How can I align these two date fields horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I mean, these two boxes are not aligned horizontally because the labels are not the same size, i want the smaller label to justify to the right, so the boxes could be alingned

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5FOA.pngstrong[CSS][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5FOA.pngstrong%5BCSS%5D%5B1%5D)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see this example here: https://codepen.io/HMokni/pen/abVOoeJ

```css
label
{
    display: block;
}

label span
{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <label>
        <span>Data inicial:</span>
        <input type="date" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>Data final:</span>
        <input type="date" />
    </label>
</form>
```

PS: You can also use flexbox (Flex-end for label and flex-start for inputs) also possible with CSS grid.

Comment: Thats great! Thank you

Answer (score -1):

One of the simplest ways to achieve this is with the margin-left CSS property, so select your lower element by Id, and play with the margin property:

```
#second_box_id {
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Comment: That works. Thanks